# Python numpy filter two-dimensional array by condition

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

Python newbie here, I have read [Filter rows of a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26154711/filter-rows-of-a-numpy-array) and the doc but still can't figure out how to code it the python way.

Example array I have: (the real data is 50000 x 10)

```
a = numpy.asarray([[2,'a'],[3,'b'],[4,'c'],[5,'d']])
filter = ['a','c']
```

I need to find all rows in `a` with `a[:, 1] in filter`. Expected result:

```
[[2,'a'],[4,'c']]
```

My current code is this:

```
numpy.asarray([x for x in a if x[1] in filter ])
```

It works okay but I have read somewhere that it is not efficient.  What is the proper numpy method for this?

#### Edit:

Thanks for all the correct answers!  Unfortunately I can only mark one as accepted answer.  I am surprised that `numpy.in1d` is not turned up in google searchs for `numpy filter 2d array`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `bool` index array that you can produce using [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html).

You can index a `np.ndarray` along any [`axis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/glossary.html) you want using for example an array of `bool`s indicating whether an element should be included. Since you want to index along `axis=0`, meaning you want to choose from the outest index, you need to have 1D `np.array` whose length is the number of rows. Each of its elements will indicate whether the row should be included.

A fast way to get this is to use [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) on the second column of `a`. You get all elements of that column by `a[:, 1]`. Now you have a 1D `np.array` whose elements should be checked against your filter. Thats what [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) is for.

So the complete code would look like:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.asarray([[2,'a'],[3,'b'],[4,'c'],[5,'d']])
filter = np.asarray(['a','c'])
a[np.in1d(a[:, 1], filter)]
```

or in a longer form:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.asarray([[2,'a'],[3,'b'],[4,'c'],[5,'d']])
filter = np.asarray(['a','c'])
mask = np.in1d(a[:, 1], filter)
a[mask]
```

Answer (score 3):

A somewhat elaborate pure `numpy` vectorized solution:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.asarray([[2,'a'],[3,'b'],[4,'c'],[5,'d']])
>>> filter = numpy.array(['a','c'])
>>> a[(a[:,1,None] == filter[None,:]).any(axis=1)]
array([['2', 'a'],
       ['4', 'c']], 
      dtype='|S21')
```

`None` in the index creates a singleton dimension, therefore we can compare the column of `a` and the row of `filter`, and then reduce the resulting boolean array

```
>>> a[:,1,None] == filter[None,:]
array([[ True, False],
       [False, False],
       [False,  True],
       [False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

over the second dimension with `any`.

Comment: While the `in1d` solution is simpler (at least in the function call), it's good to understand and use this solution as well.  It's a kind of solution that works in many other cases.

Comment: Yes, I agree myself that the solution with `in1d` is better. I wasn't aware of its existence; even tried to google a "vectorized in" before answering, but, for some reason, couldn't find anything.

Comment: I looked at the `in1d` code.  I think in this case it is building the same mask, only iteratively on `filter`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
>>> a[numpy.in1d(a[:,1], filter)]
array([['2', 'a'],
       ['4', 'c']], 
      dtype='|S21')
```

Also go through http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html

Answer (score 0):

In this case where the `len(filter)` is sufficiently smaller than `a[:,1]`, `np.in1d` does an iterative version of

```
mask = (a[:,1,None] == filter[None,:]).any(axis=1)
a[mask,:]
```

It does (adapting the `in1d` code):

```
In [1301]: arr1=a[:,1];arr2=np.array(filter)
In [1302]: mask=np.zeros(len(arr1),dtype=np.bool)
In [1303]: for i in arr2:
      ...:     mask |= (arr1==i)
In [1304]: mask
Out[1304]: array([ True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

With more items in `filter` is would build its search around `unique`, `concatenate` and `argsort`, looking for duplicates.

So it's convenience hides a fair amount of complexity.