# Find indexes by numpy where

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause

I have numpy array list:

```
x = ["A", "A", "B", "A", "C", "D", "B"]
```

For finding indexes of `"A"` I use `np.where(x == "A")` and it works fine.
How can I find indexes of `"A"` and `"B"`?

I used:

```
np.where(x == ["A", "B"]) 
np.where(x in ["A", "B"])
np.where(x == any(["A", "B"]))
```

But it didn't help me.

Comment: Divakar - your duplicate is missing the accepted answer, the one using the logical_or of masks.  Doesn't look like a good duplicate to me. :)

Comment: I just noted in another possible `duplicate`, that for a case like this, `np.in1d` (the accepted answer in the other duplicate) probably using the `logical_or` answer given here.  Look at the code for `in1d`.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/38924371/901925

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `|` or [`np_logical_or`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.2/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html) for element-wise OR:

```
x = np.array(x)
np.where((x=='A') | (x=='B'))
Out: (array([0, 1, 2, 3, 6], dtype=int64),)

np.where(np.logical_or(x=='A', x=='B'))
Out: (array([0, 1, 2, 3, 6], dtype=int64),)
```

Comment: If I have big condition, i.e x=='A', x=='B', x=='C', x=='D'. How can I use list for it? like x == something of ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] ?

Comment: You can use `in1d`: `np.in1d(x, ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])` (This will be the condition inside np.where)