# filter condition for plotting

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have 1000 text files and each file contains 6 columns. I want to plot 2 columns which are my x and y by applying a condition on the 6th column. I want to have x and y which have zero value in the 6th column. I could write how to plot all without considering the condition like below:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l = [f for f in sorted(os.listdir('.')) if f.startswith('file')]

maxnum = np.max([int(os.path.splitext(f)[0].split('_')[1]) for f in l])
l = ['file_%d.out' % i for i in range(maxnum)]


for i, d in enumerate(l): 
    a = np.loadtxt(d).T 
    num = os.path.splitext(d)[0] 
    plt.plot(a[0], a[1], c=cmap.to_rgba(i+1),label=num[-3:], lw=0.75) 
    #plt.colorbar(cmap, ticks = c)
#plt.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1)) 

plt.xlabel('X Axis')
plt.ylabel('Y Axis')
plt.title("Longterm simulation")
```

I know the condition should be defined when I am plotting, in the for loop but I can realize how to do that.

Comment: What condition are you looking to apply? Do you mean you want to filter the data to only include those points where the value in column 6 meets some condition? I.e. you're asking: how can I filter a 2d numpy array to only contain rows where the value in some column meets some condition?

Comment: @Grismar Yes, I'd like to filter the 6th column and plotting 2 first columns which have a non-zero value in the 6th column. I mean filtering x and y that have zero value in the 6th column.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python numpy filter two-dimensional array by condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38910258/python-numpy-filter-two-dimensional-array-by-condition)

Comment: @Grismar Unfortunately it does not work for mine.

Comment: If you've tried something that is similar, please update your example with the code you tried, so people can point out what needs to change specifically. The answer in the linked question is actually answering exactly your question.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green checkmark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the following change: (The 6th column in python has the index of 5)

```
plt.plot(a[0][a[5]==0], a[1][a[5]==0], c=cmap.to_rgba(i+1),label=num[-3:], lw=0.75)
```