# NumPy - get index of row with sum of row greater than 10

Tags: python, numpy

**I have following Array:**

```
a = np.array([1,2,9], [5,2,4], [1,2,3])
```

The task is finding the indexes all rows with a row sum greater than **10**, in my example the result should look like [0, 1]

I need a filter similar to the one recommended in this post:
[Filter rows of a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26154711/filter-rows-of-a-numpy-array)

However, I only need the indexes, not the actual values or an own array of them.

My current code looks like this:

```
temp = a[np.sum(a, axis=1) > 5]
```

How do I get the initial indexes of the filtered rows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `np.argwhere()` like so:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> a = np.array([[1,2,9], [5,2,4], [1,2,3]])
>>> np.argwhere(np.sum(a, axis=1) > 10)
[[0]
 [1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check where the sum is greater than `10` and obtain the indices with [`np.flatnonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html):

```
a = np.array([[1,2,9], [5,2,4], [1,2,3]])

np.flatnonzero(a.sum(1) > 10)
# array([0, 1], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use :

```
temp = np.sum(a, axis=1) > 10
np.arange(len(a))[temp]
```

Answer (score -1):

i try more than one code. The best seems to be the second version:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,9], [5,2,4], [1,2,1]])
print(a)

%timeit temp = a[np.sum(a, axis=1) > 5]
temp = a[np.sum(a, axis=1) > 5]
print(temp)

%timeit temp = [n for n, curr in enumerate(a) if sum(curr) > 5 ]
temp = [n for n, curr in enumerate(a) if sum(curr) > 5 ]
print(temp)

%timeit temp = np.argwhere(np.sum(a, axis=1) > 5)
temp = np.argwhere(np.sum(a, axis=1) > 5)
print(temp)

%timeit temp = np.flatnonzero(a.sum(1) > 10)
temp = np.flatnonzero(a.sum(1) > 10)
print(temp)
```

The results are:

```
[[1 2 9]
 [5 2 4]
 [1 2 1]]
The slowest run took 12.37 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that     an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.47 µs per loop
[[1 2 9]
 [5 2 4]]
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.09 µs per loop
[0, 1]
The slowest run took 9.83 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that     an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.3 µs per loop
[[0]
 [1]]
The slowest run took 6.78 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.8 µs per loop
[0 1]
```