# Filtering Numpy Array representing state

Tags: python, numpy

There are various questions regarding filtering of the numpy arrays including:

[Filter rows of a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26154711/filter-rows-of-a-numpy-array)

But I have a slightly different issue:

```
>>> x = np.empty(shape=(5,), dtype=[('ts', 'i8'), ('data', 'i8')])
>>> x['ts'] = [0, 1, 2, 5, 6]
>>> x['data'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> x
array([(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (5, 4), (6, 5)],
      dtype=[('ts', '<i8'), ('data', '<i8')])
>>> x[(x['ts'] > 2) & (x['ts'] < 4.9)]
array([], dtype=[('ts', '<i8'), ('data', '<i8')])
>>>
```

This is exactly what I would expect.  However, I need the filtered array to include `5` as well.   Is there a way to filter it other then with a `for` or a `while` loop iterating over rows of the array and including the row with index following the last row matching the condition?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you need to include "`5` as well"?

Comment: @dumbPy I need to filter based on `ts` where the end condition is < 5 but I need to have the row where `ts` == 5 also included.

Comment: what's wrong with good old `<= 5`? `x[(x['ts'] > 2) & (x['ts'] <= 5)]`

Comment: @dumbPy Nothing if you know that 5 is the next `ts`.  When I have to filter I don't know that the 5 is the next `ts`.  All I know is the minimum and maximum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't find a built-in numpy solution for this kind of 'positive lookbehind' matching problem. Maybe something like this will do:

```
idx_l = np.where(x['ts']<=2)[0]
idx_r = np.where(x['ts']>=4.9)[0]
x[idx_l[-1]+1:idx_r[0]+1]
```

To prevent `IndexError` in case `idx_l` or `idx_r` is empty:

```
idx = np.concatenate([idx_l[:], idx_r[1:]], axis=0)
np.delete(x, idx)
```

This approach solves the problem when the filtering condition doesn't return any index from which you can take an offset (to include the boundary value). However it will run slower since `np.where` is called twice.